# Mongo query data fetch condition issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Sample input

```
[{
    leadId : 20,
    status: in-progress,
    date: '07-03-2022',
    score:{
        create: 30,
        start: 45,
        in-progress: 90
    }
},
{
    leadId : 21,
    status: start,
    date: '06-03-2022',
    score:{
        create: 30,
        start: 45,
        in-progress: 90
    }
},
{
    leadId : 22,
    status: start,
    date: '05-03-2022',
    score:{
        create: 30,
        start: 45,
        in-progress: 78
    }
},
{
    leadId : 23,
    status: in-progress,
    date: '02-03-2022',
    score:{
        create: 30,
        start: 12,
        in-progress: 61
    }
}]
```

Output :

```
[{
    leadId : 20,
    status: in-progress,
    date: '07-03-2022',
    score:{
        create: 30,
        start: 45,
        in-progress: 90
    }
},
{
    leadId : 23,
    status: in-progress,
    date: '02-03-2022',
    score:{
        create: 30,
        start: 12,
        in-progress: 61
    }
}]
```

I need to fetch the records, if the current status value is greater than 60 within the score column.

Note status column value is dynamically updated

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear from the question , but I guess you need something like this:

```
  db.collection.find({
       "score.in-progress": {
     $gt: 60
    },
      "status": "in-progress"
  })
```

afcourse compound index on {score_in_progress:1,status:1} or {status:1,score_in_progress:1} is very likely to be created

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z6iiD0zwwu7)